# Oracle SQL - Single table record Count by ID, Grouped by Week, including Nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I am an experienced systems DBA, but it's been many years since I've dealt w the Applications/SQL side of things, so please pardon my ignorance here.  My skills are a little rusty.

**The Problem:**

I have a single table that contains a list of Student ID's and the date each student submitted an assignment.

```
Table: STU_TEST_RESULTS

STUDENT_ID  RECEIVED_DATE
----------  -------------
0030        01/10/2022
0030        01/10/2022
0121        01/11/2022
0121        01/06/2022
0127        01/04/2022
0438        01/04/2022
0438        01/11/2022
```

( Note: This is a 3rd party product, I have no say in the table design. )

**My Attempted Solution:**

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID as c_ID, to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IYYY') as c_YEAR, to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IW') as c_WEEK, count(*) as c_Count
FROM STU_TEST_RESULTS
GROUP BY STUDENT_ID, to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IYYY'), to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IW')
ORDER BY STUDENT_ID, to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IYYY'), to_char(RECEIVED_DATE,'IW')
;
```

**Current Results:**

```
C_ID   C_YEAR  C_WEEK  C_COUNT
----   ------  ------  -------
0030   2022    02      2
0121   2022    01      1
0121   2022    02      1
0127   2022    01      1
0438   2022    01      1
0438   2022    02      1
```

**Desired Results:**

```
C_ID   C_YEAR  C_WEEK  C_COUNT
----   ------  ------  -------
0030   2022    01      0 ***
0030   2022    02      2
0121   2022    01      1
0121   2022    02      1
0127   2022    01      1
0127   2022    02      0 ***
0438   2022    01      1
0438   2022    02      1
```

I need to get those empty/null/blank/zero rows in the result set somehow too.

I feel like there needs to be some sort of self-join going on here, but don't know how to make that mesh with the "group by" clause.

Comment: [mre] PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. PS It is not helpful to say you searched (or to dump links looked at). Summarize how relevant research did or didn't help with the problem. PS "close" & "feel" don't tell us anything. [ask] [Help] PS "left join"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on wording posts here. I did spend an entire day googling and searching Stackoverflow before posing my question, as I have found many solutions that way in the past. Making posts on a forum looking for answers is always sort of a last resort/hail mary for me, which is why I've only just now created an account.

Comment: Also, I did know I'd need a left outer join of some sort, but wasn't sure how to make that work w the added complications of being a self-join _and_ segregating the data by week (the "partition by" was my missing link).  Like I said, I don't do this kind of work that much anymore, but ya know, staffing shortages... 

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
WITH calendar (week, max_week) AS (
  SELECT MIN(TRUNC(received_date, 'IW')),
         MAX(TRUNC(received_date, 'IW'))
  FROM   stu_test_results
UNION ALL
  SELECT week + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         max_week
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  week < max_week
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IYYY') AS c_year,
       TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IW')   AS c_week,
       student_id,
       COUNT(s.received_date) AS c_count
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN stu_test_results s
       PARTITION BY (s.student_id)
       ON (c.week <= s.received_date AND s.received_date < c.week + INTERVAL '7' DAY)
GROUP BY
       TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IYYY'),
       TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IW'),
       student_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2390d83d9cbd3d9117f3f4ec497828b5)*

However, in Oracle 11g, recursive queries are bugged and although the syntax above is supported it won't generate the expected rows and you need to iterate differently:

```sql
WITH calendar (week) AS (
  SELECT min_week + INTERVAL '7' DAY * (LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   (
    SELECT TRUNC(MIN(received_date), 'IW') AS min_week,
           TRUNC(MAX(received_date), 'IW') AS max_week
    FROM   stu_test_results
  )
  CONNECT BY LEVEL - 1 <= (max_week - min_week)/7
)
SELECT student_id,
       TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IYYY') AS c_year,
       TO_CHAR(c.week, 'IW')   AS c_week,
       c.week,
       COUNT(s.received_date) AS c_count
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN stu_test_results s
       PARTITION BY (s.student_id)
       ON (c.week <= s.received_date AND s.received_date < c.week + INTERVAL '7' DAY)
GROUP BY
       student_id,
       c.week
ORDER BY
       student_id,
       c.week;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE STU_TEST_RESULTS (STUDENT_ID, RECEIVED_DATE) AS
SELECT '0030', DATE '2022-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0030', DATE '2022-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0121', DATE '2022-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0121', DATE '2022-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0127', DATE '2022-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0438', DATE '2022-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0438', DATE '2022-01-11' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | STUDENT_ID | C_YEAR | C_WEEK | WEEK | C_COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0030 | 2022 | 01 | 03-JAN-22 | 0 |
> | 0030 | 2022 | 02 | 10-JAN-22 | 2 |
> | 0121 | 2022 | 01 | 03-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | 0121 | 2022 | 02 | 10-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | 0127 | 2022 | 01 | 03-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | 0127 | 2022 | 02 | 10-JAN-22 | 0 |
> | 0438 | 2022 | 01 | 03-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | 0438 | 2022 | 02 | 10-JAN-22 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2390d83d9cbd3d9117f3f4ec497828b5)*